# jQuery: Adding element after nth element

Tags: jquery

I need help in adding an element at a particular location in the page body.

Here is my page code.

```
<div id="div1>
  <label id="label1"></label>
  <input type="text1"></input>
  <!-- Insert button here -->
  <span id="span1"></span>
</div>
```

I want to add a button at the location where I have put a comment above using jQuery. If the page syntax is fixed, is there a way I can add an element as a third child of the parent div? I do not want to put placeholders and do a string replace.

Thanks.

Comment: `type="text1"` shouldn't that be `type="text" name="text1"`?

Comment: I know that you said *the page syntax is fixed*, but I'm a firm believer in defensive programming. So, you should ask yourself, if a new element is added to `#div1`, how will it affect things? Well, if its added before the input, you will have to adjust your code to now insert the button as the *fourth* child. Is it safer to assume that the button will always go right after the `input` element? If so, I would avoid adding after a certain index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#div1').children(':eq(1)').after('<button/>');​​​​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hdWTc/1)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.insertAfter($('#div1').children().eq(1));
```

This will insert the `button` after the 2nd child of #div1

Answer (score 1):

```
function insertAfterNthChild($parent, index, content){
    $(content).insertAfter($parent.children().eq(index));
}

// Usage:
insertAfterNthChild($('#div1'), 1, '<button>Click me!</button');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has made an `nth-child()` selector for just this purpose.

```
$("input:nth-child(1)").after( "<your html here>" );
```

Comment: `:nth-child` is from the css3 spec and is 1 indexed not 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways.. below is one,

```
//                  v--- Change n to insert at different position
$('#div1 :nth-child(2)').after('<button>Test</button>');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/m5Gyz/

Answer (score 0):

use : http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
   $("input:nth-child(1)").after('<input type="button" value="button"/>');
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/JB4fr/1/

Comment: This doesn't answer the part of _is there a way I can add an element as a third child of the parent div_